# Bayesian Problem... I think

Tags: statistics, bayesian, conditional-probability

Let X be the number of coin tosses until heads is obtained. Without knowing that the coin is fair, I assume that the probability of heads is uniformly distributed.

How would I find the distribution of X. From my knowledge I would need to first know the conditional distribution : $X\mid Y=y$ , correct? Should I be able to get this from the given information?

I also need to show that the expected value of X,  $E[X]$ does not exist.

Comment: "I assume that the probability of heads is uniformly distributed." Does that mean you're assuming the coin is fair?

Comment: What does $Y$ denote?

Comment: I assumed $Y$ was uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$, and the condional probability of a head when the coin is tossed, given $Y$, is $Y$.  Ideally the posting would have been explicit about this.

Comment: Strictly speaking "Bayesianism" means adherence to a degree-of-belief interpretation of probability as opposed to a frequency interpretation.  A frequentist my say that the probability of getting a $1$ when a die is thrown is $1/6$ because a $1$ appears $1/6$ of the time, but a frequentist will not assign a probability to the statement that there was life on Mars a billion years ago.  A Bayesian will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $Y$ is a random variable uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$.
\begin{align}
\Pr(X=x) & = \mathbb E(\Pr(X=x\mid Y)) = \mathbb E\left( (1-Y)^{x-1} Y\right)
= \int_0^1 (1-y)^{x-1} y f_Y(y)\,dy \\[8pt]
& = \int_0^1 (1-y)^{x-1} y \,dy = \int_0^1 u^{x-1}(1-u)\,du = \int_0^1 u^{x-1} - u^x \, du \\[8pt]
& =\frac1x - \frac{1}{x+1}.
\end{align}

**Postscript some hours later:** Suppose one wants to know the conditional probability distribution of $Y$ given $X$.  The fact that $X=x$ means that when the coin was repeatedly tossed, the first time a "head" appeared was on the $x$th trial.  Suppose instead one had observed the random variable $W$, defined as the number of "heads" in the first $x$ trials.  If it had turned out that $W=1$, then that would not imply that $X=x$, but it would at least be consistent with $X=x$.  Here's an exercise: Show that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given that $X=x$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $Y$ given that $W=1$, despite the fact that $\Pr(X=x) \ll \Pr(W=1)$.

Comment: @Micheal Hardy Thank you. I have a few questions about your solution, particularly about the $X|Y$ distribution. When solving I would have initially thought that X is distributed by $Fs(p)$ i.e. the the first success distribution. Are you saying that $Y=p$. That is, $X|Y$ is distributed on Fs given that $Y$ is the parameter $p$? Could you please comment to help me understand how you set the problem up.

Comment: I'm assuming $X$ is the number of independent Bernoulli trials needed to get one success when the probability of success on each trial is $Y$.  Your posted question doesn't mention anything about a parameter called $p$.

Comment: I guess I'm asking is X the parameter for the X|Y distribution? I am trying to understand why $E[X]$ does not exist.